# calculating ratio

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called exchanges in which I have the site names and gender I need to `group by` and calculate the ratio of genders.

```
siteName  gender
 facebook   M
 Google     F
 facebook   M
 facebook   F
Google     M
 facebook   F
 Google     M

Result
 siteName  ratio
facebook    50% 
 Google      33%




SELECT siteName,gender,
  (SUM(CASE WHEN gender='M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/
  COUNT(*))*100 as male_percent
FROM siteslist
GROUP BY siteName
```

I'm not sure how I can count the number of males ('M'); my query gives either 0% or 100%

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT siteName,gender,
, Sum( CASE WHEN gender='M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) 
/ Count(*) * 100 As male_percent
FROM siteslist
#U may need to change the next two line to work correctly so first try without them
GROUP BY siteName
Order By male_percent Desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try something like

```
SELECT siteName,
    gender,
    (COUNT(CASE WHEN gender='M' THEN 1 END)/ COUNT(*)) * 100 as male_percent
FROM siteslist
GROUP BY siteName
```